# Rails 4: Ajax link uses data stored in JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4. How can I use data stored in JS with an ajax link?

1. Client - User clicks a link called "Save Graph".
2. Client - The AJAX call uses data stored in JS (e.g. "Graph.graphName" and "Graph.graphType").
3. Client - The link sends an AJAX call to to "graph#create".
4. Server - Graph#create processes the data, and creates a new graph.

Here is the code I'm trying to use with Rails:

HTML:

```
<%= link_to "Save Graph", ???, remote: true %>
```

How should I specify the controller? How can I attach more data to the AJAX call before it is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your link to the following:

```
<%= link_to "Save Graph", '#', data: { grurl: create_graph_path }, id: 'a_specific_id' %>
```

and in a js file loaded in your page:

```
$('#a_specific_id').on('click', function(){
  $.post($(this).data('grurl'), {name: Graph.graphName, type: Graph.graphType});
});
```

Comment: got it - so basically just don't use rails built in "remote: true" and still write js to submit AJAX?

Comment: @DonnyP that's how I would do it, I currently can't think of another way